# Get previous value of a dataverse field

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

I've created a flow that is triggered "When a row is added, modified or deleted". It will send an email to me with the current values of the row. If the row was modified, is there a way to check the previous values? Ideally I can include it in the email, but I couldn't find any "previous" values when I try to select the dynamic content / expression.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have auditing enabled for the specific table you are using in your trigger action?

If so you could query the audits table for this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/auditing/overview#retrieve-audit-history
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/reference/entities/audit

Below is an example with the Accounts table.

*1. Add a list rows. Filter on the _objectid_value for the record you want to check the audit history*

[image]

*2. In a Compose use the following expression to retrieve changedAttributes collection within the changedata property of the first record*

```
json(outputs('List_rows')?['body/value'][0]['changedata'])['changedAttributes']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this that I have found is that the Audit table is apparently designed for reporting purposes and there is a delay before the record is created.  Additionally, there will be multiple changes and if the record is not there yet, you will get the previous record.